# Error while trying to create user through Powershell with the privilege of Power User

Tags: powershell, windows-xp, powershell-remoting

I tried manually creating a local user account in a windows xp when logged in as a user whose is a member of Power Users group. The user got created.

But when i tried creating the user remotely through invoke -command passing the credentials of the user who is a Power Users gives the following exception :

```
Connecting to remote server failed with the following error message :
Access is denied. For more information, see the about_Remote_Troubleshooting Help topic.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the default PowerShell session configurations, **only** users who are member of the local **Administrators** security group can establish PowerShell Remoting sessions.

If you want a member of the **Power Users** security group to be able to connect to a PowerShell Remoting session, you will have to create a custom PowerShell session configuration, or modify one of the built-in ones.